# Общий вопрос о сборке из исходников

Tags: gcc, linux, rpm, makefile, perl

Добрый день,

Вопрос простой, но я не знаю куда копнуть.. Собираю перловый модуль из сырцов (принципиально из них, сейчас вопрос не в инструменте).

на первой же команде

```
perl Makefile.PL
```

получаю

```
perl Makefile.PLWarning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lperl
```

Умом, могу предположить, что нет файлика с описаниями для pkg-config а-ля perl.pc, где указаны пути до заголовков, либы и прочие опции компиляции. Но для перла никогда не было его.

В Readme указано, что

> Next, edit Makefile.PL and change LIBS and INC to include the appropriate    path information to the required libMagick library. You will also need    library search paths (-L) to JPEG, PNG, TIFF, etc.

Я открываю Makefile.PL, нахожу секцию LIBS и пишу туда путь до libperl.so

```
'LIBS' => [ "$LIBS_magick", "-L/usr/local/lib64/perl5/5.14.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE" ],
```

и получаю вполне прогнозируемый ответ

```
[root@mcenter mydir]# perl Makefile.PLWarning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lperl
```

Что делать? )

Comment: Что пишется в .configure и Makefile, которые создаются во временных директориях? Кстати, можно ли в Makefile.PL передавать многоэлементный массив в качестве значения 'LIBS', не следует навесить сначала `join`? Ну и поменять порядок LIBS и LIBPATH тоже?

Comment: configure я вообще никакого не вижу.. а что именно интересует в создающемся Makefile? вот он http://pastebin.com/Gtmt4yXeмассив в LIBS можно, так изначально было написано'LIBS' => [ "$LIBS_magick"], я лишь добавил элемент..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модули perl собираются с использованием цепочки `autoconf`/`automake`. Сообщение

```
 Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lperl
```

Генерируется при выполнении скрипта `configure`, когда тот тестирует окружение.

На причину возникновения сообщения указывает следующая строчка из `Makefile`:

```
#     LIBS => [q[-L../magick/.libs -lMagickCore -lperl -lm -L/usr/local/lib64/perl5/5.14.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE], q[/usr/local/lib64/perl5/5.14.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE]]
```

Таким образом развернулась переменная `$LIBS_magick`. Поскольку область действия опции `-L` распространяется только на следующие за ней по порядку библиотеки, компилятор не может найти `libperl.so`. Следующий вариант должен решить вопрос с порядком опций.

```
'LIBS' => [ join("-L/usr/local/lib64/perl5/5.14.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE","$LIBS_magick") ],
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, но результат операций точно такой же как и до правки 'LIBS'. А вот поиск -lperl удалось побороть создав симлинку /usr/lib64/libperl.so.5.14.1 -> /usr/local/lib64/perl5/5.14.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.soкак бы это по идиотски не звучало, но это реально работает..